# rsync --exclude-from 'list' file not working

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to complete an unfinished transfer from a remote server to a local machine using

```
rsync -a user@domain.com:~/source/ /dest/
```

where `/dest/` is the location of the partially completed transfer. However, due to bandwidth concerns I need to run rsync to a `/tmp_dest/` on a different machine that does not have a copy of `/dest/`, from where I can then later move `/tmp_dest/` to `/dest/`

The solution I have come up with thus far is to use rync's `--exclude-from` option, using a file containing a complete list of files from `/dest/`.

The command would look something like this

```
rsync -a --exclude-from 'list.txt' user@domain.com:~/source/ /tmp_dest/
```

At this point I feel as though I have scoured everywhere for a solution and tried every variant I came across.

This included relative and absolute paths for the `'list.txt'`

relative:

```
path 1/file 1
path 2/file 2
```

--or--

absolute:

```
/absolute/source/path 1/file 1
/absolute/source/path 2/file 2
```

I have tried the above with combinations of including `-` to explicitly exclude that line (where I have seen examples of people wanting to also `+` other files)

```
- /absolute/source/path 1/file 1
- /absolute/source/path 2/file 2
```

I have tried putting leading `**/` in front of the file paths to rectify the relative path problem

```
**/path 1/file 1
**/path 2/file 2
```

I have also tried navigating to the directory containing `'list'` and executing rsync from there, to avoid the issue where rsync looks for

```
/path/to/the/list/something1/to.exclude
/path/to/the/list/something2/to.exclude
/path/to/the/list/something3/to.exclude
```

and undoubtedly finding nothing

I have also ensued that the correct line breaks are being used in the 'list' file. *i.e.* `LF` (Unix) line breaks.

---

I have tried to create the `'list'` with the following command

```
find . -type f | tee list.txt
```

this initially created a file looking something like this

```
./yyyy-mm-dd folder 1/sub folder [foo]/file.a
./(yyyy) folder 2 {foo2}/file.b
./folder, 3/sub-folder 3/file.c
```

as you can see, there are spaces and other characters in the file paths, but from my current understanding, this shouldn't affect. But perhaps I am mistaken and will need to escape any characters with special meaning, which I may then need help with

which I then perform a replace on `./` in notepad++ or some other text editor that preserves the `LF` (Unix) line breaks to get the desired result.
(*e.g.* as above, I've tried replacing `./` with nothing, with `/absolute/path/for/source/` noting the leading slash, or even double wildcards to match any parent tree structure containing the files.

The only thing I feel that I haven't tried is escaping the spaces in the file names and paths, but I have read that this shouldn't be an issue.

Perhaps I am overlooking something and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notepad++? Are you _sure_ you're using Linux? :-P Anyway, I did some tests and I cannot reproduce this failure. If the paths in `list.txt` are relative to `source/`, without `./` at the beginning, with or without `-`, with or without `**/`, my rsync correctly excludes them from the transfer. My suggestion: see if you can reproduce this issue with a local transfer, i.e. just copying between folders on the same system, with just a few files.

Comment: Yes notepad++  @david-z :P that's on a Windows box (Atom from atom.io was freezing on launch, but that's another problem for another day). I'm using ssh to run rsync on the zfs server in question. I'll give that a shot, although I'm starting to think it's the special characters `[` throwing it off at the very least. I'm not sure what "pattern" `--exclude-from` uses (is it regex), but there seem to be some characters that need to be escaped [link](https://www.boards.ie/b/thread/2056322749)

Comment: If that's the case, there is little hope of anyone being able to answer this question without knowing exactly which filenames are and aren't working for you. Part of the reason I advise you to reproduce it with a small local transfer is so that, if you don't solve it yourself, you can post a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) list of filenames that will allow others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Making headway here @davidz. I have been able to (mostly) get it working locally with a large sample set of folders. It seems that `[` indeed does have special meaning to `--exclude-from` and must be escaped. I was able to generate the list using with `ls` and `sed` to append a forward slash to the end of every line with `s/$/\//` and globally escape all open brackets `[` with `s/\[/\\\[/g`, which ended up looking something like this `ls /source/ | sed 's/$/\//;s/\[/\\\[/g' | tee /home/rsync.exclude`.

Comment: I then tested with something like `rsync -anv --exclude-from=/home/rsync.exclude /source/ /empty_dir/ | tee /home/rsync.output`. The only folder that rsync didn't exclude had three consecutive dots in the file path occurring at the beginning. Other folders that had three consecutive dots at any position (including the end) were not affected. So, `foo.../` would be excluded, but `...bar/` would not.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I was simply overlooking the fact that Linux treats files starting with a `.` as hidden files and should have been using `ls -a` as opposed to simply `ls`. I also noted that the two inclusion of the following files `./` `../` in the list did not seem to effect `--exclude-from`. So at this point I just need to test this with a remote transfer `rsync -a --exclude-from=list user@domain.com:~/source/ /dest/` and report back.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem and I'm not dealing with hidden files or embedded spaces or unusual characters. It just plain doesn't work the same way with `--exclude-from filename` as it does with the same list of entries excluded with a bunch of `--exclude pattern` args on the command line. Something is fundamentally different about how they are parsed or filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Path relative to the source directory should work.
So for example:

```
rsync -ar test1/ test2/ --exclude-from=list.txt
```

Given the following directory structure

```
test1
├── subdir
│   ├── subdir2
│   └── testF3.txt
├── testF1.txt
└── testF2.txt
```

The exclude file:

```
testF2.*
subdir/subdir2/*
```

You can also use ** to match any subdirectory.

**Make sure that you don't have any extra spaces in your paths (including trailing whitespace) because that's included in the pattern.**

Comment: Exclude patterns NOT beginning with a slash are considered not anchored to the source directory, and can match any part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you use slashes at the end of the source directory name, your exclusion patterns are relative to the source directory, and cannot be absolute paths:

```bash
rsync -av --exclude-from=exclude-file.list /source/dir/ /backups/dir
#                                                     ^ slash here
```

```
# exclude-file.list
# Exclude everything under /source/dir/excluded
/excluded
```

Whereas without the slash:

```bash
rsync -av --exclude-from=exclude-file.list /source/dir /backups
#                                                     ^ no slash here
```

```
# exclude-file.list
# Exclude everything under /source/dir/excluded
/source/dir/excluded
```

**Caveat**: Exclude patterns NOT beginning with a slash are considered not anchored to the source directory, and can match any part of the path:

```
# exclude-file.list
# Exclude everything under /source/dir/.git, /source/dir/project/.git,
# as well as any files named .git
.git
```

From `rsync(1)`:

> A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination. You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing directory on the destination. In other words, each of the following commands copies the files in the same way, including their setting of the attributes of `/dest/foo`:
>
> ```
> rsync ‐av /src/foo /dest
> rsync ‐av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Here is from rsync man page how to use "--exclude-from":
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE

Use the following command:
rsync -a --exclude-from=list.txt user@domain.com:~/source/ /tmp_dest/

And also it is better to use full path name of list.txt file

Comment: Thank you, but there appears to be no difference between `rsync -anv --exclude-from=/home/rsync.exclude /source/ /empty_dir/` and `rsync -anv --exclude-from '/home/rsync.exclude' /source/ /empty_dir/`. I was a little confused at first when I was seeing common usage of the latter, but as far as I can tell, there is no difference between the two. Can you please explain what you mean by it being better to use the full path name of list.txt.

Comment: If there was a problem with not using a full pathname for the list.txt file, then rsync would say so. This advice about the full pathname is neither necessary nor relevant.